# Group same date values in PivotTable

Tags: excel, date, grouping, pivot-table

I have some data in a pivot table which is basically customer and the (sum) of their transactions by date per year. The issue I have is that I can't group the dates by month. I tried grouping but it didn't work.

```
           Values          
Row Labels     DATE  TRANSACTIONS AMOUNT EUR_EQUIVAL   Max of xyz 
             Jul-10 1   15.000,00        15.000,00     15.000,00
             Sep-10 1   15.000,00        15.000,00     15.000,00
             Oct-10 1   15.000,00        15.000,00     15.000,00
             Oct-10 1    5.000,00         5.000,00      5.000,00
             Nov-10 1    1.250,00         1.250,00      1.250,00
             Dec-10 1   15.000,00        15.000,00     15.000,00
             Jan-11 1    7.000,00         7.000,00      7.000,00
```

So from above I want to  "merge the Oct-10" values.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Excel recognises the `DATE TRANSACTIONS` field as a `date` data type, then right clicking within the field on the pivot and selecting the `group and show detail` option within the context menu should achieve what you're after.

If this doesnt work, and you only know the month, try changing the data - e.g. `1 Sep 2010` for the Sep-10 values etc.